# Do we want hats 2014 edition?

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

For those new to the site. StackExchange has a little winter themed event in December for sites to participate in called [Winter Bash](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/) (2014 link).

[image]

Basically, users earned "hats" for their gravatars by completing certain tasks (similar to badges).

Certain actions would trigger the user receiving a hat, which their gravatar could then "wear". For example, editing a post would yield an editor-themed hat (fedora with pen) to the editor.

From previous years:

- Users had their entire hat collection on http://winterbash2013.stackexchange.com.
- Individual users who didn’t want to participate, didn’t want to see hats, and/or are generally anti-hat had an "I hate hats" option available..
- The only visual change to the site itself was the presence of the hats and the "I hate hats" button in the footer.
- If we choose to accept, the event will run from **15 December 2014** to **4 January 2015**. After the time period, all the hats go away into Last Year's Hat Bin.
- We need to decide if we want hats by **December 1**

This is totally optional so do we want them?

**For those who don't want to participate, there will be an option  in the site footer to disable these.**

---

## Update:

I submitted a reply, we will have hats.

Comment: sure, hats wold be great! as long as I get one that shoots blue lasers. and can melt through other people's reputation

Comment: Sounds great to me!

Comment: Let's do it! As long as people can disable it, I don't see why not!

Comment: One question, will we be able to see what hats are available and how to get them when the event starts?

Comment: @NoviceInDisguise yep. There are also mystery hats that you might need a certain activity, login date etc to unlock. FUn stuff, you will see in a few days.

Answer (score 9):

To elaborate on [GiantCowFilms's answer](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/536/2217), I see no down side to running the event. It is stressed that there is a opt out button, so this is just for blender.se addicts to have a little more fun.

Lets have a great winter / Christmas / New year season, and collect lots of hats.

Comment: I totally agree!

Answer (score 5):

Yes, **I Want Hats!!!!!!!** Please please please... :)

Answer (score 4):

I think that this activity would help promote active participation by all members.
Since people can disable the display and participation in the event, I do not see any issue with continuing. Judging from the overwhelmingly positive response from multiple members, I would strongly recommend hosting the event.

Answer (score 0):

I want one like this, and I want it **NOW**:
http://www.litekul.se/wp-content/uploads/2013/10/kung-kanin.jpg
(And that person, by the way, is the Swedish king being the victim of somebody's creativity).

Answer (score -2):

Am not especially a fan of hats, a few times I've noticed people attempting to **game** the system - eg: https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/563/why-do-my-posts-never-get-downvoted *(yes, I know SE is about gamification to some extent... but this can get in the way)*

Its fine to have, just don't really take much interest in them and if users are messing around with answers to get hats rather than help people (too much), I would rather not have them.

Comment: I agree but the site is run by the community and as an optional SE event, the majority opted for it. It's just for a couple weeks and on the plus side, there are more avid users about the site and spammy content quickly gets flagged. I'm on the lookout for such content and I and some users with the privilege have already deleted several posts that weren't deemed useful. Warnings issued as well.