# Winter bash 2015 Countdown

Tags: discussion, winter-bash

Last year there was the [2014 Winter Bash.](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/535/do-we-want-hats-2014-edition)

Is there going to be a 2015 Winter Bash, and if so, when?

We already knew by November 21st that we had the option to opt into the winter hats, but it is now November 29th (nearly December) and no one knows whether or not, or even when the 2015 hats will be.

Comment: Probably better asked on the [main meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com).

Comment: We will usually put up a post when it's time to see if people want to participate.

Comment: @iKlsR A better question would be, when will that post be?

Comment: @X-27 When we know.

Comment: lol, ok :-) I guess we just wait......

Comment: Got an email from SE "This year's event will start on 14 December 2015 and run up to and including 03 January 2016."

Comment: Cool! Can't wait for the craziness to begin :D

Answer (score 7, accepted):

*whistles*

[Winter Bash 2015](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: Thanks! Is that countdown in minutes?

Comment: Yes, it's minutes.